# Limit existence and notation

Tags: limits

I'm confused about the existence of the limit of a real-valued function $f: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and notation.

Suppose that $\forall \epsilon>0$ $\exists \delta_{\epsilon}>0$ s.t. $\forall$ $0<|x-a|<\delta_{\epsilon}$ we have $0<|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$. Then we can write $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f(x)=L$ which denotes that "the limit of $f(\cdot)$ for $x$ approaching $a$ exists and is equal to $L$".

Suppose instead that the function $f(\cdot)$ goes to $+\infty$ when $x \rightarrow a$. If I have understood correctly the definition of limit, in this case "the limit of $f(\cdot)$ for $x$ approaching $a$ does NOT exists". My question is: why do we write $\lim_{x \rightarrow a} f(x)=+\infty$ when the function has no limit?

Comment: You are correct. Usually the definition is extended by saying something like $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = \infty$ **iff** for all $N$ there is some $\delta>0$ such that if $|x-a| < \delta$ then $f(x) > N$.

Comment: Equivalently, one sometimes sees "for each $\epsilon > 0$  there exists $\delta_{\epsilon}>0$ such that $0<\frac{1}{f(x)}<\epsilon$ whenever $0<|x-a|<\delta_{\epsilon}$".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just shorthand or notation for a specific case of the limit not existing. The notation contains more information than mere non-existence of a limit though. Indeed if $f(x) \to \infty$ as $x \to a$ then
$$ \forall h > 0 : \exists \delta > 0 : x \in \mathbb{R} : |x - a| < \delta : f(x) > h$$

Comment: Ok, but despite notation, when I'm asked to show that the function has a limit, it means that I have to show that the function has a limit which is $<\infty$ and $> -\infty$, right?

Comment: Yes. It is just notation.